# How to debug Unity/mono code on Linux/VsCode

Tags: unity, debugging, linux, visual-studio-code

I am new to Unity and I have been fighting with VSCode and debugging.

I am trying to attach a debugger to Unity to test some code that run in the editor without running the app ( kind of Unity extension debug )

Apparently there was an VsCode extension for this this but has been [deprecated](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug)

Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install this extension:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.mono-debug
2. Create a **launch.json** file in `<your Unity project dir>/.vscode/launch.json` with this content

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Unity Editor",
            "type": "unity",
            "request": "launch"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. In Unity click in the bottom right the debug icon
4. In VsCode `Run -> Start Debugging`

Enjoy